# Delete TLabel in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tlabel

I currently create a two TLabels and a TEdit dynamically, naming them LblDesc+i, EdtAmount+i and LblUnit+i - Where i is an integer that I iterate up by one each time I add those 3 elements. The data in the elements are just for simulation purposes.
My problem now is deleting the three objects. Ive tried with free and FreeAndNil, no luck at all.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
procedure TForm1.BtnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LblDesc := TLabel.Create(Self);
  LblDesc.Caption := 'Item '+IntToStr(i);
  LblDesc.Name := 'LblDesc'+IntToStr(i);
  LblDesc.Left := 16;
  LblDesc.Top := 30 + i*30;
  LblDesc.Width := 100;
  LblDesc.Height := 25;
  LblDesc.Parent := Self;

  EdtAmount := TEdit.Create(Self);
  EdtAmount.Text := IntToStr(i);
  EdtAmount.Name := 'EdtAmount'+IntToStr(i);
  EdtAmount.Left := 105;
  EdtAmount.Top := 27 + i*30;
  EdtAmount.Width := 60;
  EdtAmount.Height := 25;
  EdtAmount.Parent := Self;

  LblUnit := TLabel.Create(Self);
  LblUnit.Caption := 'Kg';
  LblUnit.Name := 'LblUnit'+IntToStr(i);
  LblUnit.Left := 170;
  LblUnit.Top := 30 + i*30;
  LblUnit.Width := 50;
  LblUnit.Height := 25;
  LblUnit.Parent := Self;

  i := i+1;
end;

procedure TForm1.BtnRemoveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Delete

end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? What happens/doesn't happen?  Anyway you need to show the code that you're actually trying to use to remove the components.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show how exactly you tried to delete these controls. In any case, you could either keep the references of created controls, or retrieve them by name with [`FindComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) later.

Comment: I reverted your last edit. If you want to show the code that ended up working, post it as an answer in the space below (headed *Your Answer*) where it belongs. Answering your own question is totally acceptable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I had issues related to the deletion of some component that I've solved setting the parent's component to `nil` but it should be no longer the case since `TControl`'s destructor - if called - already does the job.

The component should be removed by simply freeing it.

```
LblUnit.Free;
```

---

If you need to find the component by its name, use [System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) or iterate on the `Components` list.

```
for i := ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do begin
  if Components[i].Name = 'LblUnit'+IntToStr(i) then begin
    //TControl(Components[i]).Parent := nil; {uncomment if you have the same issue I've had}
    Components[i].Free;
  end;
  . . .  
end;
```

---

**EDIT**

If the index `i` used for the component's name construction `'LblUnit'+IntToStr(i)` doesn't lie in the range `[0..ComponentCount-1]`, the index has to be modified accordingly.

Comment: This Ive tried, the problem is it never finds the component. When debugging, it cycles through components and never finds it.

Comment: maybe the `i` in the `BtnAddClick` is greater than `ComponentCount-1`

Comment: The debugger on Componenets[j].Name says: "Components = '[' expected, but end of file found. The i starts at 1 when the first component is added.

Comment: the above compiles fine for me on XE4

Comment: It complies fine, it just doesnt find the component.

Comment: start `i` with `0` or use `1+i` where `i` appears between the `begin end` block in my code

Comment: If I replace "Components[j].Name = 'LblDesc'+IntToStr(i)" with "Components[j].Name = 'LblDesc2'" - It removes the 2nd label just fine

Comment: `i` and `j` are different variables :-s

Comment: They are both Integers. When the debugger reaches j=4 and i=4 (which it does when cycling through), it does nothing.

Comment: @TomBrunberg *What makes you think...* ->  in a comment the OP states that his `i` starts with `1` and in his code `i := i+1` so it was my - maybe wrong - assumption. I've already warned the OP about the value of `i` in a previous comment

Comment: I found the error and corrected it. The code mentioned above works. EOD.

Comment: @TomBrunberg That's what I meant with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454111/delete-tlabel-in-delphi/35454492#comment58607929_35454492). The OP can do something like `if Components[5+i].Name`: only the OP knows

Comment: @TomBrunberg agree, I'm going to edit with the tip. Thank you

Comment: "Set the component's Parent property to nil before freeing it." Could you explain why this is needed?

Comment: @KromStern there's no need indeed: `TControl`'s destructor already sets the `Parent` to `nil`. I had issues related to that long time ago and I've maintained this practice

Comment: Could you change your answer accordingly? Thanks

Comment: @Krom and @@Tom ok, so you guys can stop kicking my ass - for today at least :D

Answer (score 0):

To delete dynamically created component, you must have valid reference to it.

You can organize own array or list to keep your objects, or use existing lists, for example - `Form.Components[]` which holds objects whose owner is `Form`.

In the second case you have to find needed objects with `FindComponent` by name or walk through `Components[]` and search for component with some feature (Name, class type, Tag etc)

Answer (score 0):

The answer that ended up working was this:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnRemoveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: Integer;

begin
  for j := ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do begin
    if Components[j].Name = 'LblDesc'+IntToStr(i-1) then begin
      TControl(Components[j]).Parent := nil;
      Components[j].Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is no need to set Parent to nil

Comment: You are better off keeping your own array/list of labels that you create, and then you can loop through that when needed.  You *can* use the `Owner`'s `Components[]` property or the `Parent`'s `Controls[]` property to manage that for you, but it is overkill considering that other controls are also in those same lists.  Better to isolate your desired controls in their own list, your code will be cleaner and safer for it.